# JSON.Parse Selecting from a Select Container

Tags: javascript, json

I have a few JSON objects, which I'm fetching data from, but I'd really like to be able to get some specific data, depending on my selection in a selection container, but I'm not sure how tell my function which selection I've chosen. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
var parsedData = JSON.parse(someData);

    $(parsedData).each(function() {
        var m = document.getElementById("measurements"); //My selection container
        var selectedValue = m.options[m.selectedIndex].text; //What's currently selected

        var data = this.selectedValue; //This doesn't work
        var data = this.Id //This works
        console.log(newData);
    });
```

Any hint appreciated.

Comment: `this[selectedValue]`

Comment: That was it. Thanks!

Comment: I'm assuming `this.selectedValue` contains server side value and `selectedValue` contains user entered value, right? If yes, I would suggest print entire parsedData and check if you are receiving selectedValue from there. Also if you can create a JSFiddle, it would be easier to understand/find solution to the issue

Comment: @Dr.Molle is there a difference between `object.property` and `object[property]`? I used to consider them one and the same.

Comment: yes, in `object[property]` a variable `property` is expected(which contains the name of the property), while in `object.property` the name of the property is `property`  . So `object.property`  is equal to `object['property']` (Note the quotes). But when there exists a variable `property` with the value `property`, then  `object.property` and `object[property]` would be equal.